# Solve in $\mathbb R^{3}$ the following system : $\begin{cases}xyz(x^{2}+y^{2})=3\\2xyz(y^{2}+z^{2})=3\\2xyz(x^{2}+z^{2})=5\end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, systems-of-equations

I would like to see the solution of the following system equation in $\mathbb R^{3}$

$$\begin{cases}2xyz(x^{2}+y^{2})=6\\2xyz(y^{2}+z^{2})=3\\2xyz(x^{2}+z^{2})=5\end{cases}$$

My try as following :

let $xyz=t$ then $x^{2}+y^{2}=\frac{t^{2}}{(yz)^{2}}+\frac{t^{2}}{(xz)^{2}}$

And : 
$x^{2}+z^{2}=\frac{t^{2}}{(yz)^{2}}+\frac{t^{2}}{(xy)^{2}}$

$y^{2}+z^{2}=\frac{t^{2}}{(xz)^{2}}+\frac{t^{2}}{(xy)^{2}}$

But I got a difficult system ??

Comment: I'd work out $(xyz)x^2$, $(xyz)y^2$, $(xyz)z^2$ etc.

Comment: Your approach is similar to the two answers and works as well. Express $x^2 + y^2 = 3/t$ etc., then simply calculate $x^2, y^2, z^2$ as a function of $t$, then calculate the product $x^2 y^2 z^2$ to get $t$ etc.

Comment: @Damien thanks , can you drop answer here to see if you agree

Comment: The system becomes $a+b=3$, $2b+2c=3$, $2a+2c=5$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Use as variables

$$xyz^3\quad xy^3z\quad x^3yz$$

Comment: I don't understand , can you complete

Comment: Using these variables we obtain a system of three equations in three unknowns.

Comment: I don't understand you , can you written ?

Comment: @Dinizemarkob : He means $(a,b,c):=(x^3yz,xy^3z,xyz^3)$ so that one gets $2a+2b=6, 2b+2c=3, 2a+2c=5$ . Then solve for $a,b,c$ and it follows: $abc=(xyz)^5 => x^2=\frac{a}{xyz}=\frac{a}{(abc)^{1/5}}, y^2=\frac{b}{xyz}=\frac{b}{(abc)^{1/5}}, z^2=\frac{c}{xyz}=\frac{c}{(abc)^{1/5}}$ and now you'll get $x,y,z$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the first equation minus the second gets us $$2xyz(x^2-z^2)=3$$Adding this to the third equation gives$$xyz(x^2)=2$$Likewise, compute $xyz(y^2)$ and $xyz(z^2)$. You can then take their product, and take the fifth root to get the value of $xyz$, after which I'm sure you can finish.

Comment: can you complete ?

Comment: Come on, I'm not going to spoonfeed you.

Comment: OK sir , thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is similar to the two first answers and works as well.

With $t = xyz$, you get

$$x^2+y^2=3/t$$

$$2y^2+2z^2=3/t$$

$$2x^2+2z^2=5/t$$

So a linear system with variables $x^2, y^2, z^2$ and a parameter $t$.

It is easy solved as

$$x^2 = 2/t$$

$$y^2=1/t$$

$$z^2=1/2t$$

We then simply calculate the product :

$$x^2y^2z^2 = t^2 = \frac{1}{t^3}$$

To get

$$t=1$$

Comment: Very nice solution @Damirn ..+1

Comment: $t $ cannot be a parameter as it depends on $x, y, z$

Comment: How do you know (from the beginning ) that $xyz$ is constant?

Comment: @dmtri In a first step you can perfectly treat it as a parameter, in order to get a simple equivalent linear system. Of course in a 2nd step you need to get back to definition of $t$ so as to finally remove it. Globally it is not treated as a parameter, only initially. This is a rather usual method.

Comment: @dmtri I did not consider it is a constant. I could have obtained different possible values for it. In this case, I would have obtained more solutions in $x, y, z$

Comment: @Damien,  I fully understand your reasoning , now, but I would call $t$ as an forth unknown. 
Thanks.